# TestNG is not running 10 threads in parallel

Tags: java, multithreading, maven, testng

I'm using Maven and Testng to run my java-Tests. I have one java class where I have 10 Tests. But for some reason only 5 tests randomly starts. Sometimes it can be 1-3-7-8-10, sometimes 1-2-4-7-9 and so on.

I need to run them in parallel, each test in each own thread all ten tests.

I tried to use `"thread-count="10"` and `thread-count="10" data-provider-thread-count="3"` but it won't help. So I decided to take a look at pom.xml. So settings below are my current latest configure. testng.xml:

```
<suite name="AllTestsSuite" parallel="methods" allow-return-values="true">
    <listeners>
        <listener class-name="basicCommands.WebDriverListener">    
        </listener>
    </listeners>    
    <test name="name">
        <classes>
            <class name="name-to-class"/>
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

maven pom.xml. I'm using maven-surefire-plugin, so in settings for this plugin I have:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemPropertyVariables>
                          ...                           
                    </systemPropertyVariables>
                    <suiteXmlFiles>
                         ...    
                    </suiteXmlFiles>
                    <properties>
                        <property>
                            <name>parallel</name>
                            <value>methods</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>threadcount</name>
                            <value>10</value>
                        </property>
                        <property>
                            <name>dataproviderthreadcount</name>
                            <value>5</value>
                        </property>
                    </properties>
                </configuration>

            </plugin>
```

What's wrong in my settings, can I start 10 tests from one class in parallel?
Thanks.

Comment: you don't have `thread-count` in example, also did you check if something else limit our threads outside testng itself?

Comment: But I have it in pom.xml. Anyway, even I've added back `thread-count = "10"` in testng.xml, only 5 threads are starting.


>also did you check if something else limit our threads outside testng itself?
how and where? Can you suggest where can I check it?

Comment: it maybe related to using WebDriver see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37304962/limiting-the-number-of-parallel-tests-with-threadcount-testng

Comment: I will take a look, but I'm not sure.. In Jenkins I see ten lines 10:54:56 Jan 26, 2021 10:54:56 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession, looks like Selenium creates 10 sessions, but simply won't start 10 tests to run.

Answer (score 0):

For God's sake how can I be so inconsiderate and miss that goddamn line.

```
private ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
```

Issue solved